# How to convert a string representing decimal number in exponential form to float in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, string, type-conversion, qstring

I have some decimal numbers in a text file represented in exponential form Eg: 144.2e-3. I want to store the values in float. In qt it returns "0" when i directly use the "number.toFloat()" method. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toFloat() should work. Check that your string contains only the number. If the string contains something else too, for example `"144.2e-3 a"`, then the toFloat() returns 0. Note that also other numbers in the string will cause the conversion to fail, for example `QString("144.2e-3 100").toFloat()` will return 0.

Additional whitespace in the number string doesn't matter, but other characters do.

Comment: i was using QString::toDouble. QString::toFloat() works directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = 3.91e+01;
double doubleValue;
stringstream valuestream(value);
valuestream >> doubleValue;
```

Using a stringstream you can convert exponential number to the datatype we require.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QString::toDouble`.

Example:

```
bool ok;
float f = static_cast< float>( QString( "1234.56e-02" ).toDouble( &ok));
```

Comment: i was using QString::toDouble. QString::toFloat() works directly. Thanks.