# Qt/C++ Convert QString to Decimal

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore

How Can I convert QString to decimal ?

In C# code it look like that:

```
public static decimal ConvertToDecimal(string tekst, bool upperOnly)
{
decimal num = 0m;
decimal num2 = 1m;
string text = upperOnly ? "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234";
int i = tekst.Length - 1;
while (i >= 0)
{
    num += text.IndexOf(tekst[i]) * num2;
    i--;
    num2 *= text.Length;
}
return num;
}
```

Comment: This may have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730594/how-to-convert-a-string-representing-decimal-number-in-exponential-form-to-float

Comment: @Rolice: that may just be a small subset of what the OP is asking.

Comment: I just refer to examples, do not deny your answer, especially with comment :)

Comment: @Rolice: fair enough. :) I think if the OP had been more clear about the exact number pattern, we could have been more specific. That is the reason why I was trying to provide all the possible options for now. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#toInt):

> `int QString::toInt(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const`
>
> Returns the `string` converted to an `int` using base *base*, which is `10` by default and must be between 2 and 36, or 0. Returns 0 if the conversion fails.
>
> If a conversion error occurs, `*ok` is set to false; otherwise `*ok` is set to true.
>
> If base is 0, the C language convention is used: If the string begins with "0x", base 16 is used; if the `string` begins with "0", base 8 is used; otherwise, base 10 is used.
>
> The string conversion will always happen in the 'C' locale. For locale dependent conversion use `QLocale::toInt()`
>
> Example:

```
QString str = "FF";
bool ok;
int hex = str.toInt(&ok, 16);       // hex == 255, ok == true
int dec = str.toInt(&ok, 10);       // dec == 0, ok == false
```

Note that depending on your exact use case, you may wish to look into the following documentations as well:

[`long QString::toLong(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#toLong)

[`qlonglong QString::toLongLong(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#toLongLong)

[`double QString::toDouble(bool * ok = 0) const`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#toDouble)

[`float QString::toFloat(bool * ok = 0) const`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#toFloat)